# как в nginx сделать красивый урл по get

Tags: веб-программирование, nginx, redirect, rewrite, site

Задача в следующем, есть в корне сайта 2 php файла index.php и product.php. Когда в index.php выбераеться продукт, идет переход на product.php?id=чтото.
Как в nginx настроить конфиг так, чтобы пользователю было видно например http://***.ru/product/чтото?
Попытался так

```
  location / {
        rewrite product.php?id=$  ^/product/$1  break;
      }
```

чет не то

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, вам надо в вашем приложении переделать ссылки, что бы они вели на `/product/ID`, а не `/product.php?id=ID`.

Во вторых, в nginx `rewrite` должен быть в другую сторону. Примерно так:

```
location /product/ {
    rewrite ^/product/(.+)$ /product.php?id=$1;
}
```

А в-третьих, лучше не делать `rewrite` в nginx, а сделать роутер в PHP.