# Как сделать rewrite по ID пользователя?

Tags: nginx, rewrite

Подскажите как сделать так, что бы в ссылка **site.com/user?id=1** пользователя была похожа на ссылку **site.com/id1** примерно как у пользователей Вконтакте?
И при вводе в адресную строку **site.com/id1** выполнялся **site.com/user?id=1**

P.S. хостинг на NGINX

Comment: дубликаты: [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/699976/178576), [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/639648/178576)

Answer (score 1):

```
rewrite ^/id([0-9]+)(/?)+$ /user?id=$1;
```

Comment: для NGINX подойдёт?

Comment: @АлександрПротасевич, да, должно.